# Should I put this filtering in SQL or my application code?

Tags: sql, database, web

Assume I have the following models in my web Application:

```
Table User:
   (attr1, attr2, attr3, ...)
Table Prize:
   (condition1, condition2, condition3, prize_val)
```

The application logic is: if a user satisfies all the conditions of a Prize, I want to grant him the prize. The condition could either be NULL (True for all users) or a specific value. Every condition can be computed with the user attributes. I can do the filtering in 2 ways:

1. Get all the prize rules from database (at most 100), and iterate the rules in my application code, checking if the current user satisfies the rule, to get a prize list.
2. User SQL to do the filtering like this:

   `SELECT prize from Prize where (condition1=NULL or condition1=user_condition1) and (condition2=NULL or condition2=user_condition2) ...`

My question is: which one is more efficient?

And a more general question is: when is it better to do filtering in application code, instead of SQL?

PS. The reason I even think about iterations in code is this: If I iterate  in code, and condition1 is NULL for a prize, I don't need to compute the condition1 value for the user (this computation can be expensive); But If I take the SQL approach, I have to pre-compute every condition value for the user.

Comment: It depends how are configured your conditions. If you have dynamic conditions (their number will vary) may be the code with `NULL` will be more easy to implement. If you have static conditions then `SQL` seems better. In general even you have to recompute each condition with `NULL` `SQL` will do it much faster than iteration.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show in more details how 2 tables will looks like. Because as I see now the conditions are in columns. They can be also in rows to allow more dynamic configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have a matrix of conditions with prize in each row.
2. The condition values can change over time along with prize value

So, it is advisable to keep in database. 
Data should be in database and logic should be in code.
In your case the conditions are providing data, which changes. But logic remains constant.

Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 7):

Rule of thumb: `SQL Query` is always more efficient when comparing with `iterations` in the code.

About filtering - when you filter on `SQL` it will return less data than if you filter in the App. Also I think that filter in the `query` is faster than filter in the `code`.

Comment: +1 - Not only that, but filtering on the database will reduce the number of bytes on the wire transferred to the client.

Comment: Just added in the aswer to the second part. 10x for remark @duffymo.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Prize table is not normalized. I see a one-to-many relationship with Condition.

When you do that your filter is a Join instead of ever-more complex WHERE clause.

In either case I think this is best done by the database. You need to take care that you deal with primary keys. Your queries will perform badly if they aren't indexed properly.